# Do electrons jump from terminal-to-terminal in the vacuum of space?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage, vacuum, space

With enough voltage, electrons can jump 'thin air' to a negative terminal or ground here in Earth's atmosphere; an example is the Tesla Coil's ability to transfer electricity without the use of a physical connection.

Consider a battery with two wires in the vacuum of outer space. With enough voltage to bolt from the positive output to the negative wire at the correct distance, would the bolt occur?

**Response to 'sammy gerbil's comment:**
To my current understanding (which may be incorrect), the electrons use the air particles in between the terminals as a path of travel to reach negative/ground. Being the vacuum of space such particles would be non existent so I assume the bolt would not occur. However the concept intrigued me and not being 100% certain with my own resolution, I took the question here.